# how to show back button on navigation bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I was practicing an application with navigation bar. I used UIBarButton to go to the next screen from the main screen.

```
UIButton *moveLeft = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [moveLeft setTitle:@"Next Screen" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    moveLeft.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0f];
    [moveLeft.layer setCornerRadius:4.0f];
    [moveLeft.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [moveLeft.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    moveLeft.frame=CGRectMake(200, 100.0, 90.0, 30.0);
    [moveLeft setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [moveLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(moveToNext) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem* barbutton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:moveLeft];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barbutton;
```

But now when the second screen appears there is no navigation bar.
Here are the screen shots of the app

[image: main screen]

[image: Second Screen]

i tried UIBarButton for back also but still navigation bar is not coming on the second screen.

```
UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                            target:nil
                                                            action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:back];
```

My question how do i show the back button the second screen?? i am not making any custom button but the default is also not coming automatically.
Please guide me.

Comment: please put your navigation bar initialization code as well. Have you set it to rootViewController?

Comment: How you are navigating to next view? Show method `moveToNext`?

Comment: self.window =[[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    firstScreen =[[TableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:Nil];
    self.navControll = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstScreen];
    [self.window addSubview:[navControll view]];
    [firstScreen.navigationItem setTitle:@"main View"];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: Thats how i set it for rootView

Comment: -(void)moveToNext
{
     SecondViewController *secondScreen = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:Nil];
    
        [self presentViewController:secondScreen animated:YES completion:nil];
    
   
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, you are presenting the next view controller, instead of this

```
[self presentViewController:secondScreen animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Do like this

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondScreen  animated:YES]
```

**Suggestion**

Instead of adding subView to the window, you should set the rootViewController of the window which is the recommended way. So change

```
[self.window addSubview:[navControll view]];
```

To

```
self.window.rootViewController = navControll;
```

Answer (score 1):

No one answered the question correctly, I met the same question, and I have solve it by myself. My solution is delete the navigation controller before the child view controller , than control drag between the tableview controller to the child view controller, select the "show"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `UINavigationController`. It will be root view controller for your app. Put mainVC into it and then just `pushViewController` second vc.

You can access navigation controller via `navigationController` method of any vc(mainVC in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Simply u can add custom back button to navigationBar

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, button_width, button_height)];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
```